# Custom camera zoom functionality on iPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, zooming

I am new to XCode. I am trying to develop a custom camera with an overlay view . I am able to load this well and it's working great.

Now I want to add zoom functionality activated with a button on the overlay view.

Can any one guide me?  I'm trying to find out how to zoom the camera, but I haven not bene able to find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cameraViewTransform` property :

> cameraViewTransform The transform to
>   apply to the camera’s preview image.
>
> @property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform
>   cameraViewTransform Discussion This
>   transform affects the live preview
>   image only and does not affect your
>   custom overlay view or the default
>   image picker controls. You can use
>   this property in conjunction with
>   custom controls to implement your own
>   electronic zoom behaviors.
>
> You can access this property only when
>   the source type of the image picker is
>   set to
>   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.
>   Attempting to access this property for
>   other source types results in the
>   throwing of an
>   NSInvalidArgumentException exception.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.1 and
>   later. Declared In
>   UIImagePickerController.h

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: Hey Jonathan ...               imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(initialTransform, MainSlider.value,MainSlider.value);  Works perfectly .......  But when i capture Photo using [self.imagePickerController takePicture];  it does not consider the Zoom ... Just take photo as normal view .....

Comment: Honestly I've never tried this method... I guess the simple way is to scale the photo twice : once during the preview, once after the photo was captured.