# want zooming functionality in iphone camera using AVFoundation framework

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I want to zoom a camera by using **UISlider** .

I have done it successfully by adjusting the **AffineTransform** of **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer**.

Here is code of it

```
-(void)sliderAction:(UISlider*)sender{
    CGAffineTransform affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(affineTransform, sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, 0);
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:.025];
     //previewLayer is object of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    [[[self captureManager]previewLayer] setAffineTransform:affineTransform];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

but when I capture it, I am getting non- zoomed object of image.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html....pls check it dear or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794892/custom-camera-zoom-functionality-on-iphone

Comment: apply the same transform to the image you've captured perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late to reply. But I am replying for future reference.
Actually what you have done in you code is only that you have changed the zoom factor of the preview layer and not the underlying output connection. But for the zoom to be originally reflected on the captured output, you must put the factor in your output connection as well. You can use something similar to below:

```
-(void)sliderAction:(UISlider*)sender
{
    AVCaptureConnection* connection = [self.photoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]; // photoOutput is a AVCaptureStillImageOutput object, representing a capture session output with customized preset

    CGAffineTransform affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(affineTransform, sender.value, sender.value);
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, 0);
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:.025];
     //previewLayer is object of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    [[[self captureManager]previewLayer] setAffineTransform:affineTransform];
    if (connection) {
        connection.videoScaleAndCropFactor = sender.value;
    }
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

And it should do the trick.

Ideally, you shouldn't perform the `connection.videoScaleAndCropFactor` change in your `Slider` routine and should place the code in your original capture routine and set it only once with the momentary value of the slider, just before calling `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` method.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

First your code zooming only layer contents not `CMSampleBuffer`. Your next work around is to make a scale on `CVPixelBuffer` from `CMSampleBuffer` and save scaled `CMSampleBuffer` to `AVWriter`. You can use [Accelerate.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/GeometricOperations/GeometricOperations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001001-CH206-SW13) to scale `CVPixelBuffer`.